# nuxt.js -> v-bind to props of <nuxt>

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have made a nuxt.js project. I'm trying to pass data to a component (nuxt). In my first vue file I have this code

```
<nuxt v-bind:cur-language="curLanguage"/>
```

In a vue file which is put in that 'placeholder' I have this

```
...
{{ curLanguage }}  
...
export default {
layout: 'default',
props: [
'curLanguage'
],
...
```

The '{{ curLanguage }}' is in my display code, the rest in my javascript code.

**Question**

Why is the curLanguage empty and am I not getting an error? With 'normal' vue, you can pass information to a component this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with your `<nuxt/>`  tag nuxt makes use of this tag for layout
So it thinks you are trying to embed layout there.
Try renaming your component tag name.

Check out [Nuxt layout docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views#layouts)

Comment: This is also related to my question. Basically Nuxt.js doesn't pass custom props on the `<nuxt />` tag. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799729/how-to-pass-props-to-nuxt-component-pages