# Make plural with nuxt/i18n using as component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I am using nuxt/i18n plugin for localize my app.

My translation json file like below,

```
{
 "key": "a car | {count} cars"
}
```

I now if i wrote as this, i could

```
{{ $tc('path.to.key',2,{count: 2}) }}
```

But how can i use this tricky while I am using this translation as below.

```
<i18n path="path.to.key">
  <template #count>
    <!-- some html code -->
  </template>
</i18n>
```

I am using this way because i need to use html code for styling to {count} variable.

How can i singular or plural this translation?

Is there any property for i18n component to use this?

Comment: can't you pass it as template props? like [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799729/how-to-pass-props-to-nuxt-component-pages)

Comment: I think this example from Vue I18n does exactly what you want: https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/api/#i18n-functional-component - you need to combine two message keys - one contains wrapping text with a placeholder which will be replaced with a result of $tc method called with the second key inside the template

Comment: @Ellrohir thanks for answer. I already use this functional component. But i can't find how can i pluralize translation while using this component.